# Joomla 3.2.3 Showplus Slider Not loading in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, joomla, mootools, uislider

I have built few websites in joomla 3.2.3 and have used showplus for image slider. In chrome the slider does not load for the first time in few sites but loads in other sites. For ex:

Issue in chrome browser

The images load in this website : http://irishotel.in/

but the images don't load in this website : http://www.theplanterscourt.com/

Comment: There seem to be a few errors in the console along with also seeing that you are loading jQuery twice which might cause conflicts. It might be a conflict with another javascript file from another extension.

Comment: one jquery is for the slider n the other is for calendar, the website works fine in mozilla and ie but creates the problem in chrome... any suggestion on what can be done.